# React-Redux Rails JSON Key Normalization and Translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, reactjs, normalization, redux

I'm a ruby developer working on a project with a Rails 4 backend and a React-Redux frontend communicating with JSON.

Is there a set of tools, industry standard processes, or practices to normalize JSON formatting between the two?

Standard Rails sends and receives snake case. E.g. { key_a: 'val a', key_b: 'val b' }

Javascript tends to be camel case. E.g. { keyA: 'val a', keyB: 'val b' }

If there isn't a common way to handle this, is there at least a common side, frontend or backend, to do the translation on

Comment: Seeing as JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation, you might say camelCase is the preferred standard. Also, lodash has a mehod to convert between the two. See for example: lodash.com/docs#camelCase

Comment: Yeah, the issue is that there's been some significant development on both ends, front and back, before this issue was addressed.  So we've got stuff stored on the client in camelCase and then the standard rails controllers expecting snake_case.  It sounds like I need to pick a side, client or server, and do the translation explicitly for each communication with the server.  It'd be nice if either there was something a little more automagic to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion we came to was that there isn't really a common paradigm for which side manages the key translation from one case (snake) to another (camel) and back.  We decided that our first criteria was going to be that if we do translation on a given side, client vs server, we're going to do both the incoming and outgoing translations on that side.  After deciding this, it was a lighter weight implementation to do it on the client side in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I was at the same situation with Rails 5. However, the way to declare keys on Redux side  is:

`const RequestKeysFromState = {
'key_a': this.state.keyA,
'key_b': this.state.keyB,
 key: this.state.key,
};`

As I've understood, this is normal usage case for JS.